# Will a UK-bought Gamecube Memory Card work in the USA?

Tags: nintendo-wii, region-lock, nintendo-gamecube

I have a UK-bought Gamecube and Wii (which I have been told will not work with US televisions), and some Gamecube games (which I have been told will not work with US Gamecubes/Wiis) - is the same true of Gamecube Memory Cards?

They were bought in the UK and a mixture of official and third party, if that makes a difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gamecube memory cards are **not region locked** however there is a special caveat to make note of. When using a different region memory card you may need to format the memory card first. Another warning to note, that when using a memory card from another region you can only save games from the same region on that memory card. For example you **cannot** save a Japanese Super Mario Sunshine save on a memory card with an American Windwaker save on it. However this restriction is only if you are playing Japanese games, NTSC-U and PAL format saves are allowed on the card but not Japanese games.

Hope this helps.

Sources: https://www.reddit.com/r/Gamecube/comments/1dlaf3/are_controllers_and_memory_cards_region_free/

https://www.reddit.com/r/Gamecube/comments/1xto9q/need_answer_within_2h_are_gc_memory_cards_region/